# SQL insert choice of column name dependant on select value

Tags: sql, sqlite

Hope the title is a reasonable description.

I have 2 tables in a db (sqlite).

```
CREATE TABLE files (
  name TEXT,
  sha256 TEXT,
  fsno INT
);

CREATE TABLE sha256 (
  sha256 TEXT,
  fs1 INT,
  fs2 INT,
  fs3 INT,
  fs4 INT
);
```

files.fsno ranges from 2 to 5.

I am doing:

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO sha256sums (sha256)  select sha256 from files;
```

Then:

```
update sha256sums set fs2 = 1 where sha256 in (select sha256 from files where fsno = 2);
update sha256sums set fs3 = 1 where sha256 in (select sha256 from files where fsno = 3);
update sha256sums set fs4 = 1 where sha256 in (select sha256 from files where fsno = 4);
update sha256sums set fs5 = 1 where sha256 in (select sha256 from files where fsno = 5);
```

Is there a way to replace these 4 updates with something in the INSERT OR IGNORE? Something like:

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO sha256sums (sha256, fs2, fs3, fs4, fs5)  
select 
sha256, fsno==2?1:0, fsno==3?1:0, fsno==4?1:0, fsno==5?1:0 
from files;
```

The DB is Sqlite.

TIA, Pete

Comment: Are there already rows in the table with those `fsno`s or `sha256` values?

Comment: Files is fully populated, sha256sums is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `case` expression:

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO sha256sums (sha256, fs2, fn3, fs4, fsno5) 
    select sha256,
           (case when fsno = 2 then 1 end),
           (case when fsno = 3 then 1 end),
           (case when fsno = 4 then 1 end),
           (case when fsno = 5 then 1 end)
    from files;
```

This assumes that that `sha256` are not duplicated in the table -- that is, that you only want the new records to change.

Answer (score 0):

Include the `fs?` columns in the `INSERT` statement and set all their values to 1:

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO sha256sums(sha256, fs1, fs2, fs3, fs4)  
SELECT sha256, fsno = 2, fsno = 3, fsno = 4, fsno = 5 
FROM files;
```

Comment: Thx but that seems to just set all the fs? values in every row to 1. I don't know if I explained it well enough with the sql above - it should set sha256sums.fs2 to 1 only when the corresponding (via sha256 match) files.fsno value is 2 etc.

Comment: You say: *files.fsno ranges from 2 to 5* and your update statements set **all** the fs? columns of the inserted rows to 1. Isn't this what you want?

Comment: Sorry must have not explained well. The update statements set fs? to 1 for the select subset where fsno = 2 (3, 4, 5 etc).

Comment: Nice that works too and is slightly neater. Is there any difference between them in what they do, speed etc? As I have 20 million rows. I already accepted Gordons answer but will change if this one is better.

Comment: I can't tell about efficiency. You will have to try them. One difference is that this code sets the columns to 1 or 0 (and not NULL).